# Remove [oops] tag as synonym of [oop] (and delete at all)

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I don't believe it's possible to say "oop" in plural.

Comment: What is the problem of having it though? Is there something else which would need to be tagged [oops]?

Comment: @Bart: What if newcomers start saying "It looks like I made a mistake in my code, so I should use this 'Oops!' tag"

Comment: Pff, as if we don't have tons of other wrongly tagged questions. Just edit it when you see it.

Comment: @Bart, nothing but feeling that something is wrong:)

Comment: OOPS = object oriented programming structure

Comment: @GemmaOrtiz, hmm, that's intersting.

Comment: To avoid confusion, how about `[OOP-Structure]`?

Comment: @A.M. or read the tag details

Comment: @RiaD what do you mean by delete at all in the title